# Django - User creation with custom user model results in internal error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users, django-managers

Ok, I know this is a silly question but I am blocked and I can't figure out what to do.

I have searched on google and stackoverflow but did not found any answer :
I tried this :

- [Adding custom fields to users in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886987/adding-custom-fields-to-users-in-django)
- [Django - Create user profile on user creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488974/django-create-user-profile-on-user-creation)
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

My model is the following :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    quota = models.IntegerField(null = True)


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

And my view for user registration is the following :

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            cd = form.cleaned_data

            #Then we create the user
            user = User.objects.create_user(cd['username'],cd["email"],cd["password1"])

            user.get_profil().quota = 20

            user.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('')

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'registration_form.html', {'form': form,})
```

The line that launches an InternalError is :

```
user = User.objects.create_user(cd['username'],cd["email"],cd["password1"])
```

And the error is :

```
InternalError at /register/

current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                password=form.cleaned_data['password'], 
                                email=form.cleaned_data['email'])
user.is_active = True
user.save()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, don't know how I missed that