# Registration of a custom user in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set a sign up page for a project.
I created a custom user class adding few optional fields:
I'm using `Django 1.5` and `Python 2.7`

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    middleschool = 'MS'
    highschool = 'HS'
    university = 'U'
    blank = '-'
    male = 'M'
    female = 'F'

    school_choices = ((middleschool, 'Middle School'), (highschool, 'High school'), (university, 'University'), (blank, 'Not defined'),)
    sex = ((male, 'Male'), (female, 'Female'), (blank, 'Not defined'),)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    school = models.CharField(max_length = 30, choices = school_choices, default = blank, blank=True, null=True) 
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = sex, default = blank, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True, null=True)
    payment_info = models.BigIntegerField(max_length = 30, blank=True, null=True)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=0, default = 0)
    premiumstatus = models.BooleanField(default = False, blank=False, null=False)
```

and added a `create_user` method as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857719/django-user-creation-with-custom-user-model-results-in-internal-error).
This is the model's method:

```
def create_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        CustomUser.objects.create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_user, sender=User)
```

this is the relative view:

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Registration(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd =form.cleaned_data
            fuser = cd['username']
            fpassword = cd['password']
            femail = cd['email']
            fname = cd['name']
            fsurname = cd['surname']
            fschool = cd['school']
            fbday = cd['birthdate']
            fsex = cd['sex']
            fcity = cd['city']

            user = User.objects.create_user(fuser, fpassword, femail)

            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")
    else:
        form = Registration()
    return render(request, "registration.html", {'form': form})
```

and the relative form:

```
class Registration(forms.Form):
    middleschool = 'MS'
    highschool = 'HS'
    university = 'U'
    blank = '-'
    male = 'M'
    female = 'F'

    school_choices = ((middleschool, 'Middle School'), (highschool, 'High school'), (university, 'University'), (blank, 'Not defined'),)
    sex = ((male, 'Male'), (female, 'Female'), (blank, 'Not defined'),)

    username = forms.CharField(label = 'Username')
    password = forms.CharField(label = 'Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    repassword = forms.CharField(label = ' Reinstert password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    name = forms.CharField(label = 'Name', required=False)
    surname = forms.CharField(label = 'Surname', required=False)
    school = forms.ChoiceField(choices = school_choices, required=False, label='What school are you enrolled?') 
    birthdate = forms.DateField(label = 'Birth date', required=False)
    sex = forms.ChoiceField(choices = sex, required=False, label='Sex')
    city = forms.CharField(label = 'City', required=False)

    def clean_repassword(self):
        repassword = self.cleaned_data['repassword']
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        if repassword != password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Verification password different from original password!")
    widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
    }
```

Now, the problem are basically two: I'm still a beginner so I dont' really understand how `create_user` works, I tried to pass `fname` and `fsurname` as an argument of said method but it wont work, it tells me that only four arguments are accepted.
Second, if i try to add any optionl info with the command showed in the link:

```
user.get_profil().sex = fsex
```

it dosen't raise any error but doesn't work either.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: If you are using Django1.5 why you do not create a custom user?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> user.get_profile().sex = fsex

You have to assign users profile to a variable to be able to modify it:

```
profile = user.get_profile()
profile.sex = fsex
profile.save()
```

**Update** Try to explicitly specify field keys when creating user, like this:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=fuser, email=femail)
user.set_password(fpassword)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Now the problem is, i want to use the default users's field for name and surname but with this solution they don't work (it works like a charm for the custom fields insted). Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Are user email, first_name fields simply ignored?

Comment: It doesn't raise any error, simply `profile.first_name = fname` do not save the name in the User default filed first_name`. Also i just realized that the email is saved without the `@provider.tld`.

Comment: Doesn't work either, but i understood why he was messin with the email, i got wrong the order of the arguments here:  `user = User.objects.create_user(fuser, femail, fpassword)` now works just fine.